# minsize() and maxsize() methods doesn't work in tkinter python(Toplevel)

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, max-size

I was recently trying to make a pdf viewer in python, so I set the minsize() and maxsize() of the window but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root4=tk.Toplevel()
root4.geometry("800x900")
root4.title("PDF Viewer")
root4.configure(bg="#202020")
root4.minsize(300, 200)
root4.maxsize(900, 800)

pdf_frame = tk.Frame(root4)
pdf_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)

scrol_y = tk.Scrollbar(pdf_frame,orient=tk.VERTICAL)
pdf = tk.Text(pdf_frame,yscrollcommand=scrol_y.set,bg="grey")

scrol_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
scrol_y.config(command=pdf.yview)
pdf.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)


pages = convert_from_path(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("pdf files","*.pdf"),("all files","*.*"))),size=(800,900))

photos = []

for i in range(len(pages)):
  photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(pages[i]))

for photo in photos:
  pdf.image_create(tk.END,image=photo)
  pdf.insert(tk.END,'\n\n')

root4.update()
root4.mainloop()
```

Comment: `but it doesn't seem to work` clarify please?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. I'm not able to shrink the toplevel below 300x200, and I'm not able to grow it over 900x800.

Comment: Are you sure it is working

Comment: @Suryanath Yes it will work, with the `Toplevel()` window only

Comment: I can't do that I was working on a project and this is the last problem I need to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your creating a parent window use `Tk()`, else using `Toplevel()` will create a `Tk()`(for which the minsize and maxsize doesnt apply) window without you asking for it and you mightve misunderstood that for your `root4` window, so just say:

```
tk.Tk().withdraw()
root4 = tk.Tk()
```

This fixed the issue of two windows popping up, for me. Keep in mind the `minsize()` and `maxsize()` works, its just that you were trying it on the wrong window.

Comment: Actually, I was writing a program where I can't use tk.Tk() instead I would have to use tk.Toplevel(). Is there any methods like maxsize and minsize that I can use with tk.Toplevel()

Comment: @Suryanath Yes it works, with `Toplevel()` i told that you were resizing the wrong window, doesnt two windows pop up, when you run your code?

Comment: Yes I would like to resize the main window how will I do that

Comment: @Suryanath I believe that, main windows can only be created with `Tk()` and `Toplevel()` will create a child window only.